# Where can I limit the processor usage of a process that is copying files?

Tags: linux, cpu, process

How can I limit the processor usage limit for the copying process when it is running?
My friend and I are planning to get a PC to host servers and we need to know how to limit this usage to the copying process because last time we did a host machine, every time we were copying new files the servers were starting to lag.

Comment: It's probably that the filesystem you are using will play a larger factor in CPU usage than the `cp` process itself. And the fs work is going to be system usage, not user.

Comment: Copying files from where to where? If you are copying files over the network it would be logical for the server to lag...

Answer (score 3):

#### Use `nice` for CPU

The CPU scheduling priority is handled with nice(1), which says:

> Run  COMMAND  with  an  adjusted niceness, which affects process scheduling.  With no COMMAND, print the current niceness. Nicenesses range from -20 (most favorable scheduling) to 19 (least favorable).

#### Use `ionice` for Disk I/O

Using `ionice -c3` will use idle priority for disk I/O. The ionice(1) manual page says:

> A program running with idle io priority will only get disk time when no other program has asked for disk io for a defined grace period. The impact of idle io processes on normal system activity should be zero.

#### Combine the Two Options

For the least impact on your system, you can combine the two. For example:

```
# Run script with lowest possible CPU and disk priorities.
nice -n19 ionice -c3 foo.sh
```

Comment: There also is `schedtool`, which sets general scheduler policy (including I/O).

Comment: do you have to repeat the nice ionice combination if you use piped commands, e.g. `nice -n19 ionice -c3 grep xyz | grep zzz` ? Is `grep zzz` also niced or do you have to repeat the `nice ionice` in front of the `grep zzz`, means `nice -n19 ionice -c3 grep xyz | nice -n19 ionice -c3 grep zzz` ?

Comment: @bzero nice and ionice propagate to subshells, so you'd need to (io)nice the *PPID* or enclose your pipelines in `(...)` or `{...;}` if you want that to work.

Comment: @CodeGnome : like `nice -n19 ionice -c3 grep xyz | (grep zzz)` ?

Comment: No, you can only do something like `(renice -n 19 -p $BASHPID; ionice -c 3 -p $BASHPID; foo | bar)` or `nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 bash -c "foo | bar"`. (Note that `{ ...; }` doesn't actually run a subshell.)

Answer (score 0):

Copying has very little CPU impact, the resource it uses is IO bandwidth.

You should prefix io-intensive commands with `ionice -c2 -n6` if you don't want them to impact other applications too much. You can also confine stuff using cgroups and the blkio controller, but that's more involved.